# what does where false mean in range aggregate function

Tags: postgresql

[src/test/regress/expected/multirangetypes.out](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/test/regress/expected/multirangetypes.out;h=ac2eb84c3af90db38a14609749a5607653d0b26e;hb=7ae1619bc5b1794938c7387a766b8cae34e38d8a)
around line 2850 to line 2860.

`select * from nummultrange_test;`
return

```
          nmr
-----------------------
 {}
 {(,)}
 {[3,)}
 {(,)}
 {(,5)}
 {}
 {}
 {[1.1,2.2)}
 {}
 {[1.7,1.9)}
 {[1.7,1.7],[1.9,2.1)}
(11 rows)
```

`select range_intersect_agg(nmr) from nummultirange_test;`
return `{}`

`select range_intersect_agg(nmr) from nummultrange_test where false;`
return
`[null]`

---

`select isempty(' {}'::nummultirange);` yield true.
`select isempty('{(,)}'::nummultirange);`  yield false.

So, What does `where false` mean?

Comment: This is an easy way to find out what the result of a query is if it contains conditions where none of the rows satisfy them.

Comment: @klin  Sorry to bother you. I guess i stuck in here> I still not getting it.

Comment: Well, `where false` is never true, so obviously the query will never return any rows.

Comment: `select 1 where false;`  return `(0 rows)`  then why here is null. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Used in this context means that the aggregate function returns one row with `null` when there are no rows that the function could aggregate. It's rather obvious but test units examine various cases including trivial ones.

Comment: seems got. after try `select sum(t) from (values(1),(2)) a(t) where false;`  seems the idea is aggregate elements while the 0 elements should yield [null] @klin thank you.

Comment: Exactly. Good example with `sum(t)`.